# Flutter: after release app can't sign in and floatingActionButton don't work

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, http-error

My app something like Udemy app, it's developed by Flutter

I was published iOS release to App store and working well
but in Android studio doing strange situation...

When I run app on emulator or real device connected to Android studio every thing working well, but when run it with command

```
Flutter run --release
```

or build the apk file or abb file
the raisedbutton with Whatsapp icon shown in image below doesn't work

[image: app First screen with raisedbutton]

**The big problem in signing page [code shown below] when user try to signin I get this HTTP try get error with message**

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences

**Note: I use word (errrrrrrrrrrrrrooooor) in code shown below to show where error message show**

after search about this error I get that we get this error when no previous values in shared preferences, but in app first use before signing I don't use shared preferences

So, I don't understand why this happen, specially in apk release and working well in test mode on emulator or real device

**Note: I was add Internet permissions in manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**So, I need help about that**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:connect/models/app_logo.dart';
import 'package:connect/widgets/app_bar_two.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/common_functions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/auth.dart';
import '../models/http_exception.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {

  final _controller = StreamController<AppLogo>();

  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  fetchMyLogo() async {
    var url = BASE_URL +'/api/app_logo';
    try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var logo = AppLogo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    _controller.add(logo);
  }
  // print(extractedData);
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.fetchMyLogo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // final transformConfig = Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180);
    // transformConfig.translate(-10.0);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBarTwo(),
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: deviceSize.height,
          width: deviceSize.width,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: StreamBuilder<AppLogo>(
                  stream: _controller.stream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Container();
                    } else {
                      if (snapshot.error != null) {
                        return Text("Error Occured");
                      } else {
                        // saveImageUrlToSharedPref(snapshot.data.darkLogo);
                        return CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: snapshot.data.favicon,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          height: 33,
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 94.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: kTextColor,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                child: AuthCard(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthCard({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _submit() async {
if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  // Invalid!
  return;
}
_formKey.currentState.save();

setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});
try {
  // Log user in
  await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
    _authData['email'],
    _authData['password'],
  );

  String deviceName;
  String deviceVersion;
  String identifier;

  final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
  try {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
      deviceName = build.model;
      deviceVersion = build.version.toString();
      identifier = build.androidId;  //UUID for Android
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      var data = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
      deviceName = data.name;
      deviceVersion = data.systemVersion;
      identifier = data.identifierForVendor;  //UUID for iOS
    }
  } on PlatformException {
    print('Failed to get platform version');
  }

  try{
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/APIs/checkIDntfr.php"),
        body: {
          'IdentifierPst': identifier,
          'userNoPst': _authData['email'],
        });

    Map<String,dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String svdIdentifier = data["svdIdentifier"];
    String svdUserID = data["svdUserID"];
    String realUserID = data["RealUserID"];

    if(svdIdentifier != "notFound"){
      if(svdIdentifier == identifier && svdUserID == realUserID){
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (r) => false);
        //CommonFunctions.showSuccessToast('Login Successful');
        CommonFunctions.showSuccessToast('Login Successful');
      } else if(svdIdentifier != identifier || svdUserID != realUserID){
        // SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        // await preferences.clear();

        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Your account is registered for another device, please contact technical support.'),
                //title: Text('Your ${svdIdentifier} ${svdUserID} ${realUserID}'),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true), // passing true
                    child: Text('Exit'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }).then((exit) {
          if (exit == null) {SystemNavigator.pop();}

          if (exit) {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          } else {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          }
        });

      }
    } else {

      try{
        var response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse("https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/APIs/userIDntfrSv.php"),
            body: {
              'userNoPst': _authData['email'],
              'dvNamePst': deviceName,
              //'dvOSPst': deviceVersion,
              'dvIdntPst': identifier,
            });

      } catch (e){
        print(e);
      }

      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (r) => false);
      CommonFunctions.showSuccessToast('Login Successful');

    }


  } catch (e) {
    //print("note that ${e}");
  }


} on HttpException catch (error) {
  var errorMsg = 'Wrong data, you can contact customers services';
  CommonFunctions.showErrorDialog(errorMsg, context);
} catch (error) {
  //const errorMsg = 'Could not authenticate!, may you need to contact to customers services via whats-app: +201033040777';
  //String errorMsg = 'Done!${error}, Go to My courses page';
```

## **Error message shown in the next line**

```
  print("errrrrrrrrrrrrrooooor ${error}");


}
setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
  height: 360,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 260),
  width: deviceSize.width * 0.8,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              //labelText: 'Email Address',
              labelText: 'Mobile',
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                //Icons.mail_outline,
                Icons.phone_android,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ), // myIcon is a 48px-wide widget.
            ),
            //keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            validator: (input) => input.length < 11
                ? "Enter valid mobile number!"
                : null,
            /*validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                return 'Invalid email!';
              }
            },*/
            onSaved: (value) {
              _authData['email'] = value;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Password',
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.vpn_key,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            obscureText: true,
            controller: _passwordController,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                return 'Password is too short!';
              }
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              _authData['password'] = value;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          if (_isLoading)
            CircularProgressIndicator()
          else
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: deviceSize.width * 0.8,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Sign In',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onPressed: _submit,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: kBlueColor),
                ),
                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 20),
                color: kBlueColor,
                textColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          /*    ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: deviceSize.width * 0.8,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Create Account',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: kGreyColor),
              ),
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 20),
              color: kGreyColor,
              textColor: kTextColor,
            ),
          ),*/
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

## Edit:

When I try to run app with command

```
flutter run --release
```

I get this 2 errors in Terminal

> E/flutter (18074): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
> E/flutter (18074):
> E/flutter (18074): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permi
> ssions/methods)

and I try to run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

... etc, and nothing new

## Update

when I updated gradle to the last version, app working well except few users still get same error
I don't understand why!

Comment: Try rebuilding the code with clean dependencies using `flutter clean` and then again building the apk.

Comment: I was try all of this commands, still get this situation